# Can an array contain integers and floats

Tags: java, arrays, types, theory

Somebody asked me: can an array in java contain integers and floats? She got that question from a teacher.

Now my answer was: yes, since you can declare an array of objects and store integers and floats in it.

But now I'm wondering if that is correct, since technically when you store Integer and Float objects in an array, it kind of does contain both types, but if you would "ask" the array he would tell you he contains Objects, and if I don't do bookkeeping or class checks there's no way to tell that there are integers and floats in the array.

On the other hand I still feel it might be the right answer since theoretically the array contains objects of both types.

So I'm asking for a smart opinion: if you were asked (in an interview, a test whatever) wether in java an array can contain integers and floats, yes or no? What would you answer?

Comment: My answer will be yes, and you explain it beautifully.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `int` of `float` does not fit into a `Object[]` array. However, by autoboxing java will put a `Float` or `Integer` into the array instead.

Both `Float` and `Integer` extend `Number`. So you can even make a array of numbers `Number[]`

Also, you can put a `int` into a `float[]`, but java will then cast the int into a float. The other way around is also possible, but precision will be lost. (edit: Even from int->float precision can be lost. float->int may lose information about the overall magnitude of the value).

The conclusion would depend on the question. For primitive datatypes a array can not contain the other datatype. If you use a Object array (Integer, Float, Number) the answer would be yes.

Comment: Strictly speaking you **can't** put an `int` into a `float[]`. The values that are stored in a `float[]` are **always** `float` values. Also: converting from an `int` to a `float` is not always lossless.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but just to be clear: your conclusion would be 'yes' ?

Comment: My conclusion would be 'yes but'. It strongly depend on how the question was asked. When you use a primitive it can't contain the other type, you can't get the other type from it, but you can put the other type in it. So strictly speeking the answer is no for primitive datatypes.
For Objects (Integer, Float, Number) the answer would be yes.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer Strictly speaking you are correct. Java applies the conversion before it put the data in the array, so the array certainly does not contain the other datatype, and neither did you put it in. However, it's perfectly valid code to write `float[] f = new float[1]; f[0] = 1;`. The other away around you need to add the explicit cast `int[] i = new int[1]; i[0] = (int) 1.0f;`.

Comment: What you say now is very interesting concerning the primitive / object aspect, since the question does not specify any further it's for everybody to figure out. If you'd be so kind to include what you just said in your answer (briefly, so people viewing this question get a clearer answer)? I'd be more than happy to grant you the answer.

Comment: Thanks! In my opinion this suffices :)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a question that has a clear-cut "yes" or "no" answer.

I can see three distinct ways in which the question can be answered in the affirmative:

1. the array could be of type `Number[]` and could contain (references to) `Float` and `Integer` objects;
2. the array could be of type `double[]` and could contain `float`s and `int`s cast to `double` (N.B. both casts are *lossless*);
3. the array could be of type `int[]` and could store `int`s as-as and `float`s converted to `int` using [`Float.floatToRawIntBits`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits%28float%29).

In case 3 (and arguably in case 2) you'd also need a parallel array that would record the type of the value stored in each element of the main array. Depending on the assumptions built into the question, this may well disqualify these as suitable answers.

If this question came up in an interview setting, I would outline the possibilities to the interviewer and ask which of the three interpretations, if any, they were looking for. If necessary, I would then elaborate further.

Comment: 2) int to float is also lossless. 2+3) you do lose the information that the original value was a int or a float. In case 3 this information was very important too. Still +1 for the smart opinion.

Comment: @Dorus: Very good point re type information, thanks. I've updated the answer. As to straight `int`->`float` type cast, this is lossy since `float` only has 23 bits for the mantissa whereas an `int` might require 31 bits.

Comment: True, i was to quick at reading the Widening Primitive Conversion. int to float might loses precision just like float to int does.

Comment: Interesting what you say about the type conversions, the point in asking this question is of course to learn more about the matter and this is why i am very glad about all the interesting facts provided. As what you say about outlining the possibilities, that seems like the best approach in a live interview. As to the original context of this question: it was an exercise exam providing no more information and you had to choose yes or no :p

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a primitive array, you can use a `double[]` as `double` can store all possible `int` and `float` values. The only information lost is whether the number was originally an `int` or a `float` (there are 33 million integers which can be either)

To store an `int` or `float` in a double[]

```
double[] d = 
int i = 
float f = 
d[0] = i;
d[1] = f;
```

To retrieve an `int` or `float` value.

```
int i = (int) d[0];
float f = (float) d[1];
```

If you use an Object[] to store any combination of Objects including Integer and Float.

Interview questions can catch out interviewees by asking them questions they have never thought about, usually because there was no good reason to do this (possibly ever) If the question sounds odd, perhaps it should. ;)

Comment: But if I store the numbers in an array of doubles, the array would than only contain floating point numbers, wouldn't it? :)

Comment: @Samuel, `int`, `float` and `double` are all bits of data. You can make them mean what ever you want. ;) To get an `int` you can do `(int) array[n]` to get a `float` you can do `(float) array[n]`

Comment: I totally agree that actually it all comes down two a bunch of ones and zeros, but i guess they aim at the higher level presentation :p

Answer (score 0):

In java there are only two data types - objects (everything that extends class Object) and primitives (int, byte, char and so on). Also, every primitive have its object sibling - for example int and java.lang.Integer

Technically, array can contain only objects.

But in java 5.0 it's possible to skip primitive-to-object conversion thanks to 'autoboxing' functions - basically it's replacing each call like 

`int myInt = 0;
array[0] = myInt;`

with


`array[0] = new Integer(myInt);`

This replacement is done automatically, however internally (in runtime) java machine will have array with objects (Integer), not with primitives (int), and this can affect performance of array operations.